# Android get arrival time from one GeoPoint to other

Tags: java, android, gps

Is there a way to get a time for car arrival from one point to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Google Web Service for that. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/
Looks like you can just send a request with origin and destination coordinates and get the travel time in either xml or json.

Comment: Yeah, it is the solution, but is there any classes for that?